# Parse JSON to mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

A get in my PHP script JSON string that looks like this (array with any objects):

```
[
    {
        "source":"symbols/2/2.png",
        "ypos":133,
        "template":"8B82CA47-41D2-D624-D6A2-37177CD82F28",
        "rotation":0,
        "type":"MyImage",
        "width":252,
        "depth":5,
        "height":159,
        "xpos":581
    },
    {
        "source":"symbols/2/2.png",
        "ypos":175,
        "template":"8B82CA47-41D2-D624-D6A2-37177CD82F28",
        "rotation":0,
        "type":"MyImage",
        "width":258,
        "depth":3,
        "height":163,
        "xpos":214
    },
    {
        "color":"0",
        "ypos":468.38,
        "fontSize":28,
        "xpos":156.95,
        "rotation":0,
        "type":"MyTextArea",
        "width":268.05,
        "depth":7,
        "height":244.62,
        "fontFamily":"Verdana Bold",
        "template":"8B82CA47-41D2-D624-D6A2-37177CD82F28"
    }
]
```

How i can save each JSON object in this array with a record in mySQL?

Comment: I thought I just answered this somewhere else

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$json = '[
    {
        "source":"symbols/2/2.png",
        "ypos":133,
        "template":"8B82CA47-41D2-D624-D6A2-37177CD82F28",
        "rotation":0,
        "type":"MyImage",
        "width":252,
        "depth":5,
        "height":159,
        "xpos":581
    },
    {
        "source":"symbols/2/2.png",
        "ypos":175,
        "template":"8B82CA47-41D2-D624-D6A2-37177CD82F28",
        "rotation":0,
        "type":"MyImage",
        "width":258,
        "depth":3,
        "height":163,
        "xpos":214
    },
    {
        "color":"0",
        "ypos":468.38,
        "fontSize":28,
        "xpos":156.95,
        "rotation":0,
        "type":"MyTextArea",
        "width":268.05,
        "depth":7,
        "height":244.62,
        "fontFamily":"Verdana Bold",
        "template":"8B82CA47-41D2-D624-D6A2-37177CD82F28"
    }
]';
//create a DB connection
con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
mysql_connect _db('your_database',$con);


$result = json_decode($json);
foreach($result as $key => $value) {
    if($value) {

            //how to use json array to insert data in Database
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO tablename (source, ypos, template) VALUES ($value->source, $value->ypos,$value->template)");
    }
    mysql_close($con);
}
```

Note: But it is recommended to use PHP Data Objects(PDO) to do database operations.
Check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Comment: Thank you, vimalnath. The code has small errors, but that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use json_decode and then construct a insert statement using the values of the array