# Parsing JSON to MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have some JSON files I want to record on MySQL, I read through some of the help topics in SO but I'm having a problem. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462105/parsing-json-to-mysql-table)  [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257694/parse-json-to-mysql)  [3](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/381669/json-to-mysql-with-php)

My JSON looks like this;

```
     {
          "hoursPlayed": 21775,
          "communityVisibilityState": 3,
          "timeCreated": 1261107470,
          "props": [
       {
          "level": 53,
          "quality": 6,
          "origin": 0,
       },
       {
          "level": 10,
          "quality": 6,
          "origin": 0,
       }
    ]
  }
```

I already created the table and its fields, but I can't figure out what to do when it comes to the "props" array in the last entry of the JSON. It is an array in itself and it should have its own MySQL table. Without the "props" part I can read, use `json_decode()` and  loop through the array to store every other value but "props" part gets me puzzled.

My table should have fields, right?

- hoursPlayed * INT
- communityVisibilityState * INT
- timeCreated * INT
- props * ??

How do I store this in a table in MySQL?

Normally;

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO my_jsonDB (hoursPlayed, communityVisibilityState, timeCreated)
VALUES (21775, 3,1261107470)");
```

What about in my case?

Comment: `I can't figure out what to do when it comes to the "props".` -- well, what do you want to do with `props`?

Comment: "props" array in JSON, after the "timeCreated"

Comment: **`well, what do you want to do with props?`**

Comment: It's just a numerical array. Use 0 or 1 to access the first or second array within props. `$json['props'][0]['level']` That said, please explain what you want to do with props.

Comment: I tried to explain it in edited version. The way you ask it, I started to think the reason I'm puzzled is my MySQL knowledge is too low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its time to take a look into the [foreign key constraints in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). Basically your Table structure will look like the below:

- Table#1 Users - `UserID | hoursPlayed | communityVisibilityState | timeCreated`
- Table#2 UserProperty - `userKey | level | quality | origin`.

Since you are using MySQL, you can look into [autoincrement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) for primary key  `UserID`. You will use this primary key, to insert as a foreign key in the `UserProperty` table.

The overall process would look like this:

- Insert a row in the first table. Get the primary key of the insertion (ie. the first column).
- Iterate over all the "props" fields:

  - Next, use the key you got in the above step, and use it while inserting the current "prop" in the second table.

Comment: I understand, thanks a lot. Before I leave, do you think it is a better idea to move everything to MySQL to read and remove entries, or just stick with old json_decode and unlink() to delete and remove that JSON.

Comment: Also, this is more like a question of Filesystem v/s Database. :-) It would be dependant on your use case. If the number of files is quite small like < 50, you can stick with it. If you have use cases of generating stats across multiple rows, like finding the top player, then moving to DB might be preferable. Also, using files and json_decode can very quickly become unmaintainable, esp. when the number of records and/or requirements change.

Answer (score 0):

Your props should be in their own table and have a foreign key reference back to my_jsonDB.

For example you should have a table called Props.

The columns would be id, my_jsonDB_id, level, quality, origin.

The first row might be:
1,1, 53,6,0

Then when you insert into the Props table, you just set my_jsonDB_id to the id that the prop data relates to in the my_jsonDB table.

Have a look at this for an example: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Text` field, for example. And use `serialize()` function before you will save it in your database.